# Where can I find exercises on functions?

Tags: reference-request, functions

I am looking for exercises on functions which deal with one to one, onto, everywhere defined, inverse functions. Can anyone suggest me a book or source from the internet where I can find such problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Most undergraduate real analysis and abstract algebra texts have problems like that in their chapters on foundations, fahad. Try Herstien's TOPICS IN ALGEBRA and Apostol's MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS to start. And there are great problems on this in Paul Halmos' NAIVE SET THEORY.too.

Answer (score 1):

Any good introductory book in mathematics should cover this material, although I don't know of any resources where this is the primary focus. One excellent book that includes material on functions in the first chapter is  Munkres' *Topology*, but it goes on to a lot of other topics that may not be relevant to you.

A good resource may be the Wikipedia pages on [functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29), and on [bijection/injection/surjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection).